# Prove that for a graph of $n$ vertex of order $k$, $\mathcal{X}(G)\geq \frac{n}{n-k}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Prove that if $G$ is a graph with $n$ vertex and all of them have $k$ neighbours, then:
$$\mathcal{X}(G)\geq \frac{n}{n-k}$$
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

We know that we can partition the $n$ vertices into $\chi (G)$ color classes, where no vertices in any class are adjacent with others in that class. And since $G$ is $k$-regular, there are exactly $n - k$ vertices that are not adjacent to a given vertex (itself, and $n - k - 1$ others). This means that every color class contains at most $n - k$ vertices (if it were more, you contradict non-adjacency of vertices in a color class). For helpful notation, let $C_i$ be the vertices in color class $i$, for $i = 1,\dots \chi (G)$. Then what we just said in formal notation is that $n = \sum_{i = 1}^{\chi (G)}|C_i|$, and that $|C_i|\leq n - k$ for each $i$. Now just put those together and you get $n = \sum_{i = 1}^{\chi (G)}|C_i|\leq \sum_{i = 1}^{\chi (G)}(n - k) = \chi (G)\cdot(n - k)$. Then just divide the $n - k$ from the RHS and you get the result.

As a side note, when you are trying to solve these types of bounds, and one side is in terms of a fraction (as in this problem), always try clearing denominators, so that the relation you are trying to prove is in terms of products and sums, rather than quotients, because in combinatorics, products and sums have a meaning, whereas quotients don't. So here, your first step should be to multiply by the $n - k$ and look at the resulting statement, and think about what this says combinatorialy. Then try proving that equivalent statement instead, using your combinatorial knowledge.

Comment: I understand the first part of your explanation but I'm not so sure about the second one. How do you know that $\chi (G) \cdot (n-k) \geq n$? I don't see the inequality part.

Comment: yeah, sorry that was a bit more terse than I had meant. I basically just re-wrote it so hopefully it should be more clear now.